# Present continuous form for oblique subject

Tags: grammaticality, passive-voice, active-voice

Someone told me that the following is not correct:

> May the blessings of god always shower on you

and should be

> May the blessings of god always be showered on you.

My friend's argument is that blessings can't shower by themselves, thus it should be in a passive form. Are both correct?

Comment: Idiomatically one uses ***upon you*** rather than *on you*.  In my mind *be showered upon you* implies more strongly that they were meant for you rather than you just getting caught in someone else's deluge.

Comment: @Jim Inspired comment. Am still giggling about the 'deluge' bit!

Comment: Are you asking about the *grammar* (both forms are entirely grammatical) or something else? If rain can shower by itself, why can't supernatural blessings? The question appears to be whether "the blessings of god" can act; this is going to be opinion-based as far as Stack Exchange objectivity goes.

Comment: Many thanks all of you. @Andrew, It is purely grammar. I also thought both are entirely correct. However, my friend said one statement doesn't and the reason given was the argument about blessings. I am only interested in grammar and not theology. I agree that my friend is making probably a theological point, although the discussion was about grammar.

Answer (score 1):

As far as grammaticality goes, any subject can have any verb.

- May light fall upon you.
- May the railway carriage transport you.
- May the cloud overshadow you.
- May blessings shower upon you.

This was demonstrated by Chomsky:

- Colourless green ideas sleep furiously.

Whether any particular sentence makes any sense semantically (or theologically) is another matter altogether.